# Actividad inusual de un codeMirror

Tags: reactjs

Les cuento, necesito editar un registro previamente guardado.
El sistema me funciona actualmente, es decir, tengo un boton que al clickearlo (editar) me lleva a una pagina con la información asociada al registro y allí puedo editarlo, todo funciona OK. El tema es el siguiente, por algún motivo (me imagino que el renderizado) cuando escribo en el cuadro solo la **primera** letra se mantiene en el lugar que tecleo, todo el resto pasa al **final** del registro.
No se donde puede estar el error y bueno, necesito su sabiduría.

**Datos extra**

1. Hice una funcion que esta agarrando el valor que contiene el onchange, si muestro el console log del evento **si** esta agarrando el valor y mi cursor se mantiene donde deberia permitiendome editar donde quiero sin irse al final del registro
2. Si seteo mi hook con el evento pasa lo que mencioné, es decir, solo la primera letra que teclee se mantiene donde tengo mi cursor, todo el resto pasa al final!

Mi hook:

```
const [editCode, setEditCode] = useState("")
```

mi useEffect:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (code) setImportar("Importar")
    code === "" ? setCleanButton(true) : setCleanButton(false)
    if (testCaseID) {
      TestCaseService.get(applicationID, category, testCaseID)
        .then(testCaseGet => {
          //console.log("ASDAS", testCaseGet.testCaseCode)//Entra 1 sola vez aunque clickee
          console.log("***entre al get***")
          console.log(!editCode ? true : false)
          //setCode(testCaseGet.testCaseCode)
          if (!editCode) setEditCode(testCaseGet.testCaseCode)
          _tags = testCaseGet.tags!;
          setTestCase(testCaseGet);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    } else {
      setTestCase(emptyTestCase(applicationID));
    }
  }, [setTestCase, applicationID, testCaseID, category, code])
```

Mi codeMirror (es un textArea)

```
           <CodeMirror
                value={testCaseID ? editCode : code}
                options={{
                  mode: 'gherkin',
                  theme: 'default',
                  lineNumbers: true,
                  tabSize: 2,
                  indentWithTabs: true,
                  indentUnit: 2,
                  readOnly: false,

                }}
                onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
                  //setCode(value)
                  if (testCaseID) {
                    console.log("MODO EDICION")
                    //setEditCode(value)
                    escribe(value)                          

                 } else {
                console.log("MODO CREACION")
                setCode(value)
              }
            }}
          />
```

Mi función que recibe el onchange

```
function escribe(e: any) {
    console.log("entre a la funcion")
    console.log(e)
    setEditCode(e)
  }
```

Si me explico mal por favor ayudarme a pulir la pregunta y si necesitan mas datos me avisan y trato de complementarlo.

Muchisimas gracias a todos!

Comment: Parece un problema con el array de dependencias del Hook, entonces el problema en general es que la función `TestCaseService` solo se dispara una vez (según tus comentarios) y debería dispararse cada que tecleas en el `textarea`, ¿Puedes confirmar? Saludos

Comment: @g.4 Se dispara una vez pero pienso que eso esta bien, ya que solo necesito 1 vez que me traiga el registro y este se setee en otra variable. El problema a mi parecer es que tal veeeez hay alguna parte que se hace un doble seteo y por eso no sabe con cual quedarse.
Digo esto porque si es que `TestCaseService` se disparara cada vez que tecleo, significa que por cada vez que presiono una tecla me traería el valor del registro que esta alojada en otra parte o no?

Comment: @Programmer89 si encontraste la solución entonces puedes publicarla en la zona de respuestas, no tienes necesidad de eliminar el post